# Delete Redundant columns in R

Tags: r, merge

I have something similar to this:

```
date        pgm      in.x     logs       out.y
20130514    na       12       j1         12
20131204    z2       03       j1         03
20130516    a01      04       j0         04
20130628    z1       05       j2         05
```

I noticed that the in and out values are always the same so I want to delete the out.y column. And I have other columns like this I want to be able to detect any .y columns that match .x columns and delete them after I do the merge.

Comment: You can use `unique(as.list(df1))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we assume all column redundancies should be removed

```
no_duplicate <- data_set[!duplicated(as.list(data_set))]
```

will do the trick.

`as.list` will convert the data.frame to a list of all its columns, and `duplicated` will return indices for those columns that have all values as a duplicate of a previously seen column.

This does not directly try to compare .x and .y columns, but has the effect of retaining one copy of each duplicated column, which I assume is the main goal. On the other hand, it will also remove any .x columns that are duplicates of another .x column.

---

If we want to retain all .x columns, even those that are duplicates, a good solution might be to do filtering **before** the merge. Assuming you have `data_x` and `data_y` that will be merged by column "identifier":

```
data_y_nonredundant <- data_y[!(as.list(data_y) %in% as.list(data_x) & names(data_y)!="identifier")]
data <- merge(data_x, data_y_nonredundant, by=c("identifier"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! This is a good solution but it only works when you don't have coluns that are different but for the time beeing have all zero values.

Comment: You are right! If all x-columns should always be kept, even if they are duplicates, it doesn't work. I have added another approach that will now.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one more variable to your dataframe which is replica of out.y

```
x <- data.frame(date  = c("20130514","20131204","20130516","20130628"),
  pgm = c(NA, "z2", "a01", "z1"), in.x= c(12, 3, 4, 5), out.y= c(12, 3, 4, 5),new.y = c(12, 3, 4, 5))

y <- x[grepl(".x|.y",colnames(x))]

 in.x out.y new.y
1   12    12    12
2    3     3     3
3    4     4     4
4    5     5     5

y$in.x==y[,c("out.y","new.y")]
     out.y new.y
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE

x <- x[,1:3]

      date  pgm in.x
1 20130514 <NA>   12
2 20131204   z2    3
3 20130516  a01    4
4 20130628   z1    5
```

Comment: simple case you can use x <- x[!duplicated(x),]

Answer (score -4):

These answers  from our colleagues are undoubtfully right, but a simpler manner is by :

```
dataframe[,5]  <- NULL
```

Comment: I doubt that this is what they're looking for

Comment: @docendodiscimus it clearly does not detect automatically the columns but it may do the trick if you are lazy (like me) and don't want to write too many lines

Comment: I don't agree on the comment for lazy people. Because you'll have to figure out each column _manually_ in this approach (it's not just about 1 column) whereas a lazy person would write code to "automate" this process

Comment: @docendodiscimus that's true, I buy you the argument

Comment: Nope, like  @docendodiscimus said I don't know which column it will be so I need an automated solution, and I am a biginner in R.